# Solution layers / Folder/project hierarchy .NET project

Tags: c#, oop, parsing, design-patterns, hierarchical-data

I'm creating project which will parse .html to database (kind of sqlite or other, it's not important yet). Database will has many tables, relationship and to understanding the schema will be some difficult, well I'll show you more simple Schema.

For example:

Models:

- `Subject`: SubjectId, Name
- `Teacher`: TeacherId, SubjectFk, Name, Surname
- `ClassRoom`: ClassRoomId, year
- `Student`: StudentId, ClassRoomFk, Name, Surname

**Relations** (*it's not important!*):

1. One subject is leading by multiple teacher, one teacher leads only one subject
2. One ClassRoom contains many students, one students belongs to only one classRoom
3. Is unique pair: TeacherId, ClassRoomId (In one classRoom can be only one object carried by a particular teacher, many teachers can not teach in a classRoom of the same subject, iam not sure...but it's not important).

Now I build a project hierarchy:

**ParseData** - solution name

**ParseData.Repository** - it contains App.Config which contains app settings to root folder where exist data.

**ParseData.Domain** - Classes for data model which will be parse, for example:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
    public int ClassRoomFk {get;set;}
}

public class ClassRoom
{
    public int ClasRoomId {get; set;}
    public List<Student> Students {get;set;}
}
```

**ParseData.Core** - contains all algorithm and Classes which will read file from path and convert data to class model, for example:

```
public class StudentParse : IEntity<Student>
{
    public Student Student {get; set;}
    public StudentParse(string filePathWithDataForStudentsFromParticularClass, int ClassRoomFk) { (...) }
    /* All methods, which will parse data to StudentModel */
}

public class ClassRoomParse : IEntity<ClassRoom>
{
    public ClassRoom ClassRoom {get;set;}
    public ClassRoomParse(string filePathWithClassRoomsData) { (...) }
    /* All methods, which will parse data to ClassRoomModel */
}

public interface IParser
{
    string filePathToMainFile {get;set;}
    List<ClassRoom> Start();
}
```

**ParseData.UI** - Console application. Here i can write some code which will present me results from featching data. For example:

```
IParser parser = new Parser(Repository.MainFilePath);
List<ClassRoom> parser.Start();

/* LINQ or other actions..save to file or something else */
```

I'm searching a knowledge how could I organize my solution to best practices. I am open to criticism about my approach and inexperience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option besides a ReadRepository and WriteRepository I mentioned earlier is to apply the [Extract, Transform, Load (ETL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) method. This is a clearer approach, mainly because the data is one-way only.

The solution would have a `ParseData.Extract` project (the ReadRepository) that loads the data from the HTML files into [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which match the data structure of the HTML files. A `ParseData.Transform` project would transform the DTOs to the database models (the entities if you're using Entity Framework for example). A `ParseData.Load` project would then serve as the WriteRepository mentioned earlier to save the entities to the database.

The `ParseData.UI` project can still be used to orchestrate the ETL process.

Comment: ye, i think that is better solution! Mr Boris, Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you have are two data sources: One to read from (the HTML files) and one to write to (the database). Ideally you would hide how the files are read from disk and how they are persisted to the database. That is what the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is for.

Your application has a clear purpose: It should import the data from the files to the database. Creating one repository would make the architecture of your application less clear. It would first 'read' from the repository only to 'write' it to the same repository again.

Because of that I suggest creating two Repository projects: One `ReadRepository` and one `WriteRepository`. That would make the console application project really simple: Instantiate the repositories, query the `ReadRepository` and save to the `WriteRepository`. The `Core` project would in effect become the `ReadRepository`. Both repositories would use the `Domain` objects.

I would also suggest to let the `UI` console application decide where the files are stored. So store the location in the App.config of the console application. That way you can perhaps overwrite the file location with a command-line parameter.